# В каком значении употреблено слово “дело ” в этом заглавии?

Tags: значения

> Дело о миллионе программистов

Источник: http://www.computerra.ru/105643/delo-o-millione-programmistov/

Comment: It looks like a poor wording. I'd use _matter_ or perhaps _agenda_.

Answer (score 6):

"Дело о миллионе программистов" means "The Case of Million Programmers".  The header is only loosely connected to the contents of the article. It is fairly common in Russian journalism.

Answer (score 2):

as this article talks about sanctions to and from Russia.

Дело in this case could be possibly used with historic reference to criminal investigations/criminal cases during soviet period, for example [Дело врачей](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctors%27_plot)

It was widely discussed in media.

It's quite common to use strong, cemented phrases in Russian journalism. I believe article has nothing to do with criminal investigation, nor with Soviet Union, but this name is used to attract attention.

Answer (score 1):

Possible translations:

- The *case* of a million programmers
- The million-programmers *affair*
- The *matter* of a million programmers

Answer (score 0):

Can be also translated as `"A point of a million programmers"`.

The article sheds light on perspectives of a million programmers due to changes happened. It touches a coming future for the whole branch of IT industry in the country. Of course as a standalone title it can be translated as

> `"A matter of ..."`,
>
> `"A case of ..."`

or something sort of

> `"An agenda is a million of programmers"`.

**But** would not first two titles sound as a court case and the latter as a listening to a law project to be accepted?

From this perspective it can be translated simply as

> `"The thing of/about a million programmers"`

or

> `"A point about..."`

with the meaning of `fate of ...`, `future (perspectives) of ...` or `comming changes for ...`

Comment: Neither "agenda" nor "point" have anything to do with it...

Comment: @MikhailT. what makes you think so?